# Problem with ajax, jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function sendValues() {
var str = $("#myForm").serialize();
var response = $('input[name=brand[]]:checked').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/trying.php?avoidcache=' + myTimestamp();",
    data: {str}
    cache: false
});
}
```

I want to be able to send the data onclick (checking the checkbox) 
and I need the checkbox to stay checked when it is sent to the server. Right now it does not stay checked, but the value of the checked is shot out.

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish..

http://www.abt.com/category/45/Bookshelf-Speakers.html

I can  get the script to filter results, but there is 2 problems with it.

- I want the ajax data to be sent to the server on click,
- I need the checkboxes that have been [checked] to stay checked once the data is sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're submitting the form via ajax, you're causing the form submission using JavaScript. I imagine that when you say *`the checkbox does not stay checked`* it's because your page is being submitted and reloaded without state.

I'd say your options are

1. Modify your PHP script to check the checkboxes if their state is checked in the database.
2. Actually submit via jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) making use of [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

   - Here's [an article that talks about this](http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-and-when-to-use-jquerys-serialize-method/).
   - You could also use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)

**Update**

1. You didn't show how you're triggering the function in the updated code but if it's on the `submit` event of a `form`, you should make sure that you `return false;` to cancel the form submission. Other than that you have some errors in your code - `{str}` is invalid syntax and is also missing a trailing comma.
2. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/gAG4a/) that submit a form on checking/unchecking checkboxes in the form using ajax. Note that message returned is always an error message since this form is running on jsFiddle.net but in your case, it will be the response of your PHP script that you will handle appropriately.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of how I would write the submit via ajax script-- thanks

Comment: @no.good.at.coding I actually have a version of this script that uses .serialize() and it worked well, the only problem is that it does not allow me to perform the ajax call upon clicking the checkbox.

Comment: @RPM What's exactly the problem in that case? Do you get an error? Could you be more specific? Provide the actual code of what you're doing? And perhaps update the question with this information?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding-- I updated the answer with an example of what exactly I am trying to do

Comment: @RPM I've linked to a fiddle showing a live example of how this might work (and it does work). Please compare with your code and see where you might be doing it wrong. Also, I've pointed out in the updated answer that your code isn't error-free. Other than that, it should work.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding- This works very well. I appreciate this. Thank you. I am looking over the code, and I am trying to figure out if I need to give each checkbox a value, and the .serialize will serialize the checkbox values and send it the php script. Thanks again.

Comment: @RPM What do you mean about giving the checkboxes values and serializing those? With the example fiddle, you'll see that the form gets serialized into something like `Box2=on&Box3=on&text=Default+value` where `Box1` is unchecked, the other two are checked and which is why they appear in the submit. The `input` field named `text` is also part of the `POST`. Note that only checked checkboxes will be submitted. So if you do not find a checkbox parameter in the received request in PHP, it was not checked.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding I acceppted it. & thank you for all your help. I really do appreciate this. What I am doing with the checkboxes is have the "Box2=value&Box3=value" the value is a number which implodes the values into a mysql query and shoots out the results. Thank you again. I'm using PHP by the way.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding- I guess a better question would be,     $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $('#response').prepend('<div class="send">' + $(this).attr('name') + ' was changed</div>');
   sendValues();
}); Where does my data from the php script get put into?

Comment: Are you asking where the data that is sent from PHP in response to this request will go? Well you need to write that part since it depends on how you want to handle and how your page is structured. The data will be available as the first parameter to the `success` function in the `ajax` call.

Comment: Yes, But I actually got the jsfiddle version to work & I got another version to work it is...href="http://vbizmarketing.com/trying.php The only problem is it does not allow for multiple check boxes to be checked

Comment: Is the page that you linked to your current code? I'm afraid you're still submitting the form the normal way and your page is reloading - you can see that from the fact that your URL in the address bar changes. You also have multiple forms with the same `id` in the `td`s before each checkbox - there should be just one, containing *all* your checkboxes. Your `ajax()` call has a `return: false`, there isn't any such parameter. What you should be doing is `return false;` i.e. return a false before calling `ajax()`. Also, do **NOT** use $('#myForm').submit() - that kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yes, that is the current code, I am still attempting to be able to implement the above code into a working piece utilizing the database and PHP. I noticed that the code you wrote, It worked for me once I hit the return key when the mouse is inside the text field.

Comment: This is what I constructed with the code that you wrote; I put the PHP script inside of it. http://vbizmarketing.com/trying2.php But I have to check the check boxes, and then hit return on the text field, and then it successfully shows those values.

Comment: Your JS is invalid on that page - the string literal for `' was changed` is not terminated correctly - a JS string literal cannot span multiple lines in that way. Just get rid of the whole statement: `$('#response').prepend('<div class="send">' + $(this).attr('name') + ' was changed
 '</div>');`

Comment: Also, you should look into using Firebug or your browser's native JS console to catch these errors. Also, it's a good practice to use `$(document).ready()` as the place where you initialize your JS.

Comment: I deleted that portion of the code, but do you see how it submits the form on enter via the text field? It will say undefined if I use the check box

Comment: That's expected behaviour - pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a form will cause it to submit. If the textbox is not needed, you can get rid of it. Otherwise, you can bind a handler to stop the default action of a form: `$('#myForm').submit(function(){return false;});`

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm trying to remove the results of the checked value when you uncheck it. Right now it only adds the Box1 was changed